# Modifying the base OpenSearch docker image to execute a set of python scripts at the startup

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, dockerfile, opensearch

#### Hello Everyone!

I am just a beginner in the field of containerized applications and I have a very specific problem.

I would like to create a Federated Full-text Search Engine, where I use OpenSearch with each instance having a separate set of data. We are also considering using ElasticSearch, hence the tag.

I would like to modify the base opensearch docker image (which can be found here: https://hub.docker.com/layers/opensearchproject/opensearch/latest/images/sha256-55f1f67e7d3645aa838b63a589bce5645154ba275814e52d4638d371ca0f8cb5?context=explore )

to run a custom set of python scripts that get a set of XML files as an input while starting the docker container.

The general idea is to start the OpenSearch image with Docker Compose and to execute a set of scripts to upload the data to the OpenSearch App. I want to run several containers in parallel, which are not the part of the same "OpenSearch Cluster", but separate entities, each with a separate set of data.

I would also like to pass the search query as a docker parameter and save the result into a file in the container's volume or send it "back" to the host machine.

So to conclude:

1. I want to pass a set of XML files into the container
2. I want to execute a set of Python scripts to upload to the Search Engine
3. I would like to execute search query and save the result to a file

##### Previous steps

Previously I have been starting up a few OpenSearch instances separately, each with a separate docker-compose file, but it is a very unefficient method, as it involves creating many separate files.

Uploading scripts have been executed on the host machine, but later down the process I have realized that in order to containerize and scale-up the project I would have to containerize the uploading process as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there particular steps with which you're having difficulty? There are many articles online covering topics like building Docker images or working with Docker compose. We can generally give you better answers if you ask specific questions.What have you tried so far? Are there particular steps with which you're having difficulty? There are many articles online covering topics like building Docker images or working with Docker compose. We can generally give you better answers if you ask specific questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.